Prefill User information in Appointment booking form in nylas
i am using nylas scheduler v3, below is my code, how can i pr-fill user data such as name, email in appointment form.
const nylasScheduling = document.querySelector('nylas-scheduling');
nylasScheduling.clientId = NYLAS_CLIENT_ID;
nylasScheduling.slug = schedulePageName;


it can be done passing bookingInfo prop as in below code
const nylasScheduling = document.querySelector('nylas-scheduling');
              
nylasScheduling.clientId = NYLAS_CLIENT_ID;
nylasScheduling.slug = schedulePageName;

nylasScheduling.bookingInfo = {
    primaryParticipant: { name : 'maaz qureshi', email: 'muhammadmaaz40@gmail.com'}
};

